# Send an http response to another site

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, web

*Noob*

How should I send a single string variable to another site from my rails app? ie the outside service sends a get request to my controller/route and then the controller must respond with the string (and I assume a response code). The string is intended to be added to their html code.

In my controller should I

```
render :text => "string"
```

or

```
respond_with("string) #as xml or json
```

or something completely different?

Comment: Do you mean "How can I build an API other applications can use?"

Comment: I wasn't sure if a single response would be considered an api but yes an api other applications can use

Comment: It could be a one method API, but an API nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Just try the following code. Here your application gives the text and json as per the request.

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.json do
     render :json => 'string'
    end

    format.html do
     render :text => 'string'
    end
 end
```